# How to create a mock in Aurelia/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, aurelia

How to create a mock object in order to test the code in TestComponent? This is what I have:
When I run, it says: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null'

app.js

```
<template>
<compose view-model="./component/TestComponent" model.bind="TestData"></compose>
</template>
```

TestComponent.html

```
<template>
 <div class="menuItem">
    <h4>ID: ${data.menu.id}</h4>
    <div class="value">${data.menu.value}</div>
    <div class="path">${data.menu.path}</div>
 </div>
<template>
```

TestComponent.spec.js

```
import {StageComponent} from 'aurelia-testing';
import {bootstrap} from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
let component;

beforeEach(() => {
  component = StageComponent
    .withResources('component/TestComponent')
    .inView('<TestComponent></TestComponent>')
    .boundTo({"menu": {"id": "3", "value": "Sample", "path": "Middle"}});
});

it('should render value', done => {
  component.create(bootstrap).then(() => {
    const nameElement = document.querySelector('.value');
    expect(nameElement.innerHTML).toBe('Sample');
    done();
  }).catch(e => { console.log(e.toString()) });
});

afterEach(() => {
  component.dispose();
});
```

});

Mock data:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "3",
  "value": "Sample",
  "path": "Middle"
}}
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to mock. If it's simply a model, then did you have a look at the doc about mocking a base model? here https://aurelia.io/docs/testing/components#testing-a-custom-element . Notice the `.boundTo({ ... })` part, it could be : `.boundTo({ menu: { id: 3 ... } })`

Comment: @bigopon I did like the example at Aurelia Doc. Now when I run it, it says "'TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null'"

Comment: it's because it couldn't find anything with `querySelector('.value')`, (returned `null`). my guess is because of this: `'<TestComponent></TestComponent>'`, try change it to `'<test-component></test-component>'`